# How to diagnose COM-callable wrapper object creation failure?

Tags: .net, delphi, com, ccw, com-callable-wrapper

I am creating a COM object (from native code) using [`CoCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
const 
   CLASS_GP2010: TGUID = "{DC55D96D-2D44-4697-9165-25D790DD8593}";

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLASS_GP2010, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, out unk);
```

Actually, I'm in Delphi, which means I call the helper function:

```
CreateComObject(CLASS_GP2010);
```

Most of the time this function succeeds. But *sometimes*, in the same executable, in the same **process**, the call to `CoCreateInstance` fails with:

```
Unspecified error (0x80004005 = E_FAIL)
```

Calling the function again may succeed, or may fail. There's no (apparent) rhyme or reason.

### It's not my COM dll

If this were a *normal* COM dll that I wrote, I would start placing `OutputDebugString` in `DLL_ATTACH`, and when someone tries to call `DllGetClassObject`, I would confirm that COM is correctly loading my DLL, and that it is correctly asking for a class to be instantiated.

Unfortunately it's not a COM dll; it's a .NET assembly dll. And the COM subsystem [does not simply](https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2230187991/siM.png) *"load"* my `dll`. Instead, COM is instructed to load `mscoree.dll`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   CLSID
      {DC55D96D-2D44-4697-9165-25D790DD8593}
         InprocServer32
            @default = mscoree.dll
```

And `mscoree.dll` exports the required `GetClassObject` function. So `mscoree.dll` is the one returning `E_FAIL`, not me. The failure never happens on my development machine, but consistently intermittently fails on the customers machines.

### How do I enable .NET logging?

The question is, since `mscoree.dll` is the one returning `E_FAIL` (rather than anything useful): how do I have it tell me what the problem is?

For example, it appears that the only customers experiencing the failure (besides being the only ones who heavily use the COM object) happen to be on Windows XP. Perhaps they are experiencing the known bug in the .NET framework (prior to version 4) where you [cannot load different versions of the .NET runtime into the same process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> doing so introduces a CLR version dependency which may conflict with the CLR version expected by the host process

This mode of failure is also noted in [an article on MSDN when using COM wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eew13bza.aspx); where you have the *option* of specifying a `clrVersion`:

> If another version of the CLR is already loaded and the specified version can be loaded side-by-side in-process, the specified version is loaded; otherwise, the loaded CLR is used. This might cause a load failure.

If this **were** the cause of my intermittent load failure on Windows XP, or with previous versions on the .NET framework, how can I get the `mscoree.dll` to tell me that?

If the cause is something else, how do I get .NET to tell me that?

Comment: You could put some diagnostics in your program to note any time `mscoree.dll` is loaded into your process. You'd note which version was loaded and then when you encounter a failure, check if you've loaded a different version during the lifetime of the process. If it is an issue with CLR version clashing, then the one plausible explanation is a naughty shell extension that uses .net when it should not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How do i log module loads at runtime? The only way i've never seen module load/unload is in Delphi's *Event Log*. **Bonus Chatter**: The casing of my first person singular pronouns is intentional.

Comment: +1; great question. You should explain that a `HRESULT` of `0x80004005` is `E_FAIL` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137.aspx) Debugging CCW and RCW stuff is hard. Is the .NET code yours? Can you debug it? This might be a good start: http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/research-topic-hidden-ccw-per-com-client-app/

Comment: I would look at using SysInternals' ProcMon to collect logs on the customer's environment.  It is an excellent resource for gathering deep system interaction logs where components don't otherwise provide them.
Running the tool does constitute a bit of a performance hit, so the customer would have to know to start log collection and then stop and send you the traces after the problem has reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the assembly binding failure logging feature - it needs to be enabled and then you can use the fusion log viewer to see the results
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Not sure how you will get this onto your clients machines.

When I first read this my first thought was given it seems most common on win xp boxes is this a .net version/ bit wise problem or is your .net dll missing a dependency not present on these machines.

Comment: The problem is that the object creates fine one moment, and then fails during the next call, then works again. The dlls are still there.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, if you were to run it in Visual Studio's debugger, you might be able to catch the first-chance exceptions and get some insight.  At the very least, you want to know what kind of error results in the E_FAIL.  You should be able to do this even if you don't have the debug symbols.

Additionally, even if you can't load multiple .NET VM's in the same process, with some manual work with the App.config and .dll manifests, you might be able to load the .dll's in the same .NET VM even though they were compiled against a different one.

Finally, check the windows event viewer under the application events to see if there is anything logged there.